# how to install Extensibility.dll for office 2003?

Tags: installation, office-2003

I have addin for office 2003 that created with IDTExtensibility2 com interface and ofice 2003 PIAs.
I am able to run the addin on development machine, but cannot cretae installer.
Ob client machine with office 2003 and 2003 PIAs Excel unable to load my addin.
Does anybody know how to create installer for IDTExtensibility2 addin?
Thank you

UPDATE
I have found that Extensibility.dll is missing on client machine, so may be have sense install Extensibility libraries? I cannot find approriate installer for Extensibility.dll installation...
So, does anybody know how to install Extensibility.dll on client machine?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess… Your client machine does not have Visual C++ runtime libraries installed. Check Windows logs for errors from *Side by Side* source.

If it is the case, you will have to run vcredist.exe for your version of Visual C++ before installing your plugin, or add merge modules to your MSI install package.

Comment: I have installed Visual C++ runtime but still does not work. I found that Extensibility.dll is missing on client machine, so may be have sense install Extensibility libraries& But I cannot find approriate installer for Extensibility.dll installation